# Visual Studio Tools Not Found Error Message

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, msbuild

I am getting the following error when trying to build a project in Visual Studio Professional 2013 Version 12.0.30723.00 Update 3 and I have .NET 4.5.2 Framework installed.

I will try to provide as much information as possible, if I leave out some missing piece, let me know please.

Description: "Visual Studio tools not found"
File: EXEC
Project: MyProjectName

I did an advanced google search on the exact phrase "visual studio tools not found" and No results found for "visual studio tools not found".

I'm thinking something is wrong with my environment but I can't figure it out.

Comment: you're inside Visual Studio building a project, and you get an error `Visual Studio not found`?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a situation where you may just need to uninstall and reinstall your visual studio environment.

Comment: I uninstalled VS 2013 and reinstalled but I am getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out this was a custom error message unique to my company. Problem was solved me tracking down the source of the message.